# Terraform issue in gitlab

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, terraform

I have an application whose build is configured in gitlab and makes use of terraform, and software is finally deployed in AWS.

I see following error during deployment:

```
null_resource.server_canary_bouncer (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "./bouncer canary -a 'my-asg':$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name 'my-asg' --query 'AutoScalingGroups[0].DesiredCapacity')"]
null_resource.server_canary_bouncer (local-exec): /bin/sh: ./bouncer: No such file or directory
Error: Error running command './bouncer canary -a 'my-asg':$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name 'my-asg' --query 'AutoScalingGroups[0].DesiredCapacity')': exit status 127. Output: /bin/sh: ./bouncer: No such file or directory
[terragrunt] 2020/11/12 12:16:31 Hit multiple errors:
exit status 1
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I don't have much knowledge of terraform and hence don't really understand what to make out of this log.

Any idea how this can be solved?

Answer (score 2):

`Output: /bin/sh: ./bouncer: No such file or directory` you are trying to run a file/script/command and it does not exist in the dir you are running terraform.